# numpy.loadtxt to load a file

Tags: python, numpy, file-upload

I have a file which looks like this:

(The full version can be accessed here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uKRgp6X6ZfQbUsEr2bQ3_ZOPZYFSjmhj/view?usp=sharing)

```
[[51, 49, array([[ 67.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  1.,  47.,   0.,   0.],
       [117.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 10., 126., 109.,   0.],
       [  7.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 90.,  50.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 50.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  4.,  69.,  40.,  49.]])], 
[70, 49, array([[ 63.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [127.,  48.,   0.,   0.],
       [118.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 52., 125.,  68.,   0.],
       [  2.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 62., 102.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 84.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 58.,  89.,   5.,  72.]])],
[75, 49, array([[122.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [120., 104.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 86.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [104.,  24.,  15.,   0.],
       [ 99.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 77.,  41.,   0.,   0.],
       [124.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [126.,  37.,  73.,  59.]])]
```

where the headings are iteration = 51, value = 49, angles = array(...), iteration = 70... and so on.

How do I go about loading this in my script? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a text file with these contents?

Comment: You can download it from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uKRgp6X6ZfQbUsEr2bQ3_ZOPZYFSjmhj/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `numpy` load methods wont work here, as the file does not have the expected format. If you are responsible for generating this file, consider using e.g. `numpy.savetxt` or `numpy.save`, so you can use `numpy.loadtxt` or `numpy.load` accordingly.

With the file you have, if the source can be trusted, a *very quick and dirty* solution would be to load this file using `eval`. However, consider reading on the [the dangers of `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/12661819), as **it can execute *any* code within that file**.

Assuming you have imported `numpy` like this:

```python
import numpy as np
```

this should work:

```python
with open('filename.txt') as file:
    contents = file.read().replace('array', 'np.array')
    data = eval(contents)
```